# Play WS - check compression headers

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I enabled gzip compression for all the responses in my web service (Play 2.4) by following [those instructions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GzipEncoding). Easy to set up, and I can see it works like a charm having checked with curl and wireshark that the responses are sent compressed.

Now I want to be a good developer and add an integration test to make sure no one breaks HTTP compression next week. Here's where the fun begins! My test looks like this:

```
"use HTTP compression" in {
  forAll(endPoints) { endPoint =>
    val response = await(
      WS.url(Localhost + port + "/api" + endPoint).withHeaders("Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip").get()
    )
    response.header("Content-Encoding") mustBe Some("gzip")
  }
}
```

However, the test fails as WS's response headers don't include content enconding information, and the body is returned as plain text, uncompressed.

```
[info] - should use HTTP compression *** FAILED ***
[info]   forAll failed, because:
[info]     at index 0, None was not equal to Some("gzip") (ApplicationSpec.scala:566)
```

Checking the traffic in wireshark when running this test I can clearly see the server is returning a gzip-encoded response, so it looks like WS is somehow transparently decompressing the response and stripping the content-encoding headers? Is there a way I can get the plain, compressed response with full headers so I can check whether the response is compressed or not?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: See my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39701208/887422) (it ended up a little bit too big for just a comment reply). I ended up using plain old Java classes and bypassing Play-WS altogether for this single test because I needed something more low-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. If I'm not mistaken , the problem here is that Netty return the content already uncompressed, so the header is removed also.

There is a configuration in AsyncHTTPClient to set that ([setKeepEncoding](http://static.javadoc.io/org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.0.0/org/asynchttpclient/DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder.html#setKeepEncodingHeader-boolean-)), but unfortunately this only works in version 2.0 and newer, and Play 2.4 WS lib uses version 1.9.x.

Either way, the client Play gives you is already configured, and I don't know if you are able to tweak it. But you can create a new client to emulate that behavior:

```
// Converted from Java code: I have never worked with those APi's in Scala
val cfg = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().addResponseFilter(new ResponseFilter {
        override def filter[T](ctx: FilterContext[T]): FilterContext[T] = {
            val headers = ctx.getRequest.getHeaders
            if (headers.containsKey("Accept-Encoding")) {
                ctx.getResponseHeaders.getHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", List("gzip"))
            }
            ctx
        }
    }).build()
val client: NingWSClient = NingWSClient(cfg)
client.url("...") // (...)
```

Again, this is just emulating the result you need. Also, probably a more clever logic than just add `gzip` as `Content-Encoding` (ex: put the first algorithm requested in "Accepts Encoding") is advised.

Comment: the header is called `Accept-Encoding`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we can't really use Play-WS for this specific test because it already returns the content uncompressed and stripped of the header (see @Salem's insightful answer), so there's no way to check whether the response is compressed.

However it's easy enough to write a test that checks for HTTP compression using standard Java classes. All we care about is whether the server answers in (valid) GZIP form when sending a request with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`. Here's what I ended up with:

```
  forAll(endPoints) { endPoint =>
    val url = new URL(Localhost + port + "/api/" + endPoint)
    val connection = url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    Try {
      new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream)
    } must be a 'success
  }
```